# Detecting if a guild.member is currently streaming and give or remove a role depending on streaming status

Tags: python, bots, discord

Looking for some help with an issue I am having with some of my code in Python, I am writing a piece of code for my discord bot to detect when someone has the Activity_type = discord.ActivityType.streaming and automatically give them a role, also detect when they are no longer streaming and take away the role.

I don't get any errors at the moment, just a huge bug. For some reason it works for some users but then starts to spam giving and removing the role when a user is actually streaming. This is a feature breaking bug and would love it if someone can explain where I am going wrong.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        activity_type = None
        streaming_role = after.guild.get_role(521744891748024330)
        try:
            activity_type = after.activity.type
        except:
            pass

        if activity_type is None:
            if streaming_role in after.roles:
                print(f"{after.display_name} has stopped streaming")
                await after.remove_roles(streaming_role)

            else:
                pass

        else:
            if activity_type is discord.ActivityType.streaming:
                if streaming_role not in after.roles:
                    print(f"{after.display_name} has started streaming")
                    await after.add_roles(streaming_role)
                else:
                    if streaming_role in after.roles:
                        print(f"{after.display_name} has stopped streaming")
                        await after.remove_roles(streaming_role)
```

Comment: In your try/except block try printing the error message. You may be running into an error you don't notice because you don't log it.

Comment: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'")
thats whats come up when i printed the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_member_update` runs on any user update, irrespective of whether it's activity-related or not. You are, however, checking the user's activity every time. (You can see a list of changes that fire this event [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update))

If the user is streaming, their activity will be `discord.ActivityType.streaming`. If they are not, it will either be `None` or a different activity.

Your code, when updating a user's role, will fire the `on_member_update` function since a role change is an update. Your code will then check if they have the streaming activity, and then will add/remove the role based on whether it already exists on the user.

The result is that while a user is streaming, the bot will add the role to the user, get notified because of the update, and see that the activity is `streaming` and that they have the role. Then the bot removes the role, which once again fires `on_member_update`, which prompts it to re-add the role and so on and so forth.

To fix this: A user having `discord.ActivityType.streaming` always means that they are streaming. If the user has this activity type, and has the role, that just means your bot has already processed the user starting to stream and there's no need to remove the role. Change your code to reflect this:

```
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        activity_type = None
        streaming_role = after.guild.get_role(521744891748024330)
        try:
            activity_type = after.activity.type
        except:
            pass

        if not (activity_type is discord.ActivityType.streaming):
            # User is doing something other than streaming
            if streaming_role in after.roles:
                print(f"{after.display_name} has stopped streaming")
                await after.remove_roles(streaming_role)
        else:
            if streaming_role not in after.roles:
                # If they don't have the role, give it to them
                # If they have it, we already know they're streaming so we don't need to do anything
                print(f"{after.display_name} has started streaming")
                await after.add_roles(streaming_role)
```

Comment: Woah, what a detailed explanation. I can totally see where I went wrong now. I didn't consider giving the role would trigger the on member update again and now i realise that, the bug is obvious. Thanks for your help!